# BadMethodCallException Method does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I am getting an issue on creating a new route, all previous routes are working. I've created an action in the controller and defined it in `routes/web.php,` but I am still getting:

> Method App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::getUsers does not exist
>   error.

I also tried with different action names but I am still getting the same error. I also regenerated the route cache but still no success.

```
Controller:-
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function getUsers(){
        echo "here";die;
    }
}

Route:-
Route::get('/admin/users', 'AdminController@getUsers');
```

Comment: What is your controller name

Comment: @Shibon AdminController

Comment: is it in folder controllers

Comment: @Shibon yes it is, all other routes for this controller is working except this one.

Comment: check namespace of the controller class

Comment: @KarolSamborski check my edited code.

Comment: Are you using `artisan cache` ?

Comment: @KarolSamborski yes

Comment: php artisan optimize:clear try after clearing cache

Comment: php artisan route:clear && php artisan view:clear && php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan clear-compiled

Comment: @Shibon still getting same error.

Comment: first of all you should check your route list by running command
php artisan route:list 
this will show all available route and you will get exact idea .

Comment: Is this the entire AdminController class, or have parts been removed?